# How do I replace duplicate strings with values

Tags: python, excel

In the first column in Excel I have car brands. In the second - models per brand.
I want to replace the identical brands with sequential numbers. Acura - 1s, Alfa romeo - 2s, etc.

I've tried this:

```
myList = []
cnt = 1
for x in brands:
  if x == brands[brands.index(x)+1]:
    myList.append(cnt)
  else:
    cnt += 1
```

To no avail. I've also tried the excel formula `=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)`, but as I understand it, I need to edit it for all brands and that just won't do, because there are 1,500+ models.

I've also tried with

```
for i,x in enumerate(brands):
  if x[i] == x[i+1]:
    myList.append(cntr)
  else:
    cntr += 1
```

But as it turns out, x[i] checks the letter of the string, and not the whole string.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: So, you have the list of brands?  Why not create a dictionary, where the key is the brand name and the value is your incrementing integer?  Now your lookup is just `branddict[brand]`.  Let the computer do the work.

Comment: Ah, that's another idea too, yes. Thank you!

As always.. I figured it out, 5 minutes after I posted the question..

I just wasn't using enumerate correctly..

Answer (score 0):

Apologies. I just wasn't using enumerate properly, as I was looking for x[i], instead of brands[i].

You can mark this as resolved / delete it.

Thank you and have a great week!